# Cardinality of intersections of lines with irregular 1-sets in the plane

Tags: geometric-measure-theory, fractals, hausdorff-measure

From Falconer's book (*The geometry of fractal sets*), Lemma 3.2 says that the intersection of irregular 1-sets with straight lines is of zero $H^1$ measure. What do we know about the cardinality of such intersections? I was trying to see if I can solve this problem for certain examples like cantor-dust sets. These are irregular 1-sets of the plane constructed as follows: Divide the unit square into $k^2$ smaller squares of side $\frac{1}{k}$ where $k \geq 3$ in the obvious way. Shade one square in each column of the array so that the centers o the square are not collinear. Construct a set $E$ by a Cantor-type process by repeatedly replacing each shaded square by a similar copy of the whole figure and taking the limit set. I tried some examples but I couldn't find any thing. Are there any results about this? Any ideas?